Content Filter iOS is not intercepting ping commands
Could you help me understand the work of the Content Filter in the following context. When I use the Network Tools app for testing ping commands for specified domains/IP addresses, the content filter (both socket and browser filtering enabled) is unable to intercept them. Is it the problem of sandbox restrictions?
However, if I use DNSProxy with NEDNSManager which I tested before, I can intercept ping of the domains but not IP addresses, which is obvious. However, why is the content filter unable to intercept traffic from the Network Tools app?
